# Jquery not selector not working on child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#ul li:not(.info)', function(){

    alert();
});
```

My html is like this

```
<ul id="ul">
<li></li>
<li><a href="#" class="info"></li>
</ul>
```

why it still trigger when I click on .info?

Comment: Your class `info` isn't defined on any LI. What is expected behaviour here? Is it to exclude any click event on anchor with class `info` or on any `li` which has an element with class `info`?

Answer (score 1):

Because your HTML defines `.info` class on the `<a>` descendant instead of the `<li>` itself, while your selector denotes `:not(.info)` which means the `<li>` is not having the `.info` class.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ul li:not(:has(.info))', function(){
    alert();
});
```

Alternatively, you can simply move your `.info` class to the `<li>` itself:

```
<li class="info"><a href="#"></li>
```

See jQuery's [has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkseexma/)

Comment: u don't have to use .has()

Comment: @JenniferAniston, Apparently you do. Unless you're going with the suggested alternative...

Answer (score 0):

can you make it this and try

```
$(document).on('click', '#ul li a:not(.info)', function(){

    alert();
});
```

Comment: You are binding click event on anchor, not `li`. It could be expected behaviour, not sure...

Answer (score 0):

`#ul li:not(.info)` looks for a class in li that is not info

```
#ul li a:not(.info) will give you the right result
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ztp2xmz/)

Comment: You are binding click event on anchor, not `li`. It could be expected behaviour, not sure...